# after function on selenium test is not defined

Tags: javascript, jasmine, automated-tests

I'm attempting to use `suite()` function from Selenium using Javascript.

The problem comes when I run the following code

```
const { Builder, By, Key, until } = require("selenium-webdriver");
const { suite } = require("selenium-webdriver/testing");
suite(function (env) {
  describe("Log in", function () {
    let driver;

    before(async function () {
      driver = await env.builder().build();
    });

    after(() => driver.quit());

    it("demo", async function () {
      //some test
    });
  });
});
```

I get the error:

`ReferenceError: after is not defined`

I think its a problem with mocha since the [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/testing/index.html) says *Provides extensions for Jasmine and Mocha.*

I have already tried with

```
yarn add mocha
yarn add Jasmine
```

but get the same error. Can anyone explain me what 'provides extensions' means?

Answer (score 3):

Method 1:

Instead of using `node test.js`, try `npx mocha --no-timeouts test.js` to run your test.

Method 2:

Set up a test script in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha"
}
```

Run your test with `yarn test test.js`

Ref:

- https://mochajs.org/#getting-started